# How to adjust or resize the background image of div dynamically based on content size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on Html and Css. I am trying to design a chart conversation like web page where i need to show the messages alternatively like one comes right another on left similar in mobile applications. For that i am using divs to contains the message and i set a background-image for it,

[image]

Here what the problem i am facing is, message are of variable size that means some may occupy 1 line and some other might 5 to 20 lines we cannot estimate it. Div background-image size is 40px height only so if i got more than 3 lines of message then it crosses the background image. Here is my Div markup

```
<div style="background-image:url('some url');padding:10px;margin:2%;word-break:break-word;width:100px;max-width:10px">Here is my content it is variable in size</div>
```

I have used the css properties like overflow:hidden but it didn't help me. Is there any way so that image or div will be automatically resized based on the content size vertically. Or other way i can follow that is closely related to my requirement. Please guide me.

Comment: What about splitting the background in three parts so only the middle part contains the text. Then you can stretch the middle part as wide as you want without making the image looking weird. Just set a minimum size for the middle element, fixed sizes for the top and bottom elements and everything else should work.

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of the CSS property `background-size` but [it won't be supported in old browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size) (mainly IE<9 which might not be a problem):

```
background-size: cover;
```

Or

```
background-size: 100% 100%;  /*x and y*/
```

Or you can try to use jQuery to deal with it.
I would recommend you to take a look at: [Perfect Full Page Background Image](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Anyway, the image will get distorted and might not look very good. What usually is done in these cases is splitting the image in 3. Top, middel and bottom,so the middle image can be repeated on the Y axis.

[image]

But, you will still having problems with the graduated background, which you might want to use as another background image or rather with CSS3...

**My advice:** less is more. Make things easier. Take a look around in other sites and see how they try to avoid complex images. If possible, deal only with CSS, avoid requests, speed up your site and bring the new minimalist style to your site.

Comment: Or he can split it vertically. Top, Mid and Down. So he can keep the text in mid.

Comment: @SoroushFalahati, true, I didn't realize he wants to expand it vertically :) thanks for pointing it out, I will update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible solution:

Just split it up into 3 `div`s.

[see here](http://jsfiddle.net/AQWSZ/1/)

It works with splitting the image into three parts:

[image] - Top

[image] - Middle

[image] - Bottom

But you should really consider building chat bubbles by using only HTML and CSS as it improves performance and lessens network requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "background-size":

```
background-size: cover;
```

Read more:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Yet I don't recommend this. You better split your image to two image and use two div.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [jquery dotdotdot plugin](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/#intro) and shrink the content of a div to a specific height and width so that it appears nicer..

You have an option to show the remaining content with a link at the end of your content allocated for the div and show the left over content may be in a popup or something you may want..

Answer (score 0):

Browser support isn't *as* good as background-size (to my knowledge), but this seems like a case for border-image.

The image you're already using as background should split fairly well and this will let the div scale without causing the left and right edges of the speech bubble to stretch in the same way they would if the background image is just stretched to fit.

More info: http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/

Answer (score 0):

background-size: 100;

or

background-size: cover;

are the CSS solutions. If this does not fit your needs, then you can use jQuery's `getWidth`, `getHeight`, `setWidth` and `setHeight` functions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RABfa/) using `background-size: 100% 100%;`

By adding a couple of <br>'s after your message, you can compensate for the pointer to the bubble in your image.

Answer (score 0):

You have loads of sites with chat bubbles made only with CSS.
Here are some examples:

http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/demo/

http://www.sitepoint.com/pure-css3-speech-bubbles/

http://www.ilikepixels.co.uk/drop/bubbler/

http://html-generator.weebly.com/css-speech-bubble-generator.html

If you have any doubt after viewing those, please ask us about it :)

Answer (score 0):

Friend,

Try add this property in the element:

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Because you set 100% of width but add to paddings and margins.

See if this working...